# Install Odoo Source dependencies on Windows 10 Error

Tags: python, windows, odoo

I am trying to install Odoo15 Source dependencies on windows 10.
I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
Then this error occurs

```
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2==2.8.6 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 28)) (2.8.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pydot==1.4.1 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 29)) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl==19.0.0 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 30)) (19.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2==1.26.0 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 31)) (1.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 32)) (223)
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial==3.4 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 33)) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil==2.7.3 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 34)) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-stdnum==1.13 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 36)) (1.13)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2019.3 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 37)) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyusb==1.0.2 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 38)) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: qrcode==6.1 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 39)) (6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: reportlab==3.5.59 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 40)) (3.5.59)
Requirement already satisfied: requests==2.22.0 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 41)) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: vobject==0.9.6.1 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 42)) (0.9.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug==0.16.1 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 43)) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd==1.2.0 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 45)) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: XlsxWriter==1.1.2 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 46)) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: xlwt==1.3.* in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 47)) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zeep==3.4.0 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 48)) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from freezegun==0.3.15->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from gevent==20.9.0->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.event in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from gevent==20.9.0->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from gevent==20.9.0->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (60.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12.2 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from gevent==20.9.0->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from ofxparse==0.19->-r requirements.txt (line 22)) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.1.4 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from pydot==1.4.1->-r requirements.txt (line 29)) (3.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.3 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from pyopenssl==19.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 30)) (36.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from qrcode==6.1->-r requirements.txt (line 39)) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from requests==2.22.0->-r requirements.txt (line 41)) (1.25.11)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from requests==2.22.0->-r requirements.txt (line 41)) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: isodate>=0.5.4 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from zeep==3.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 48)) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property>=1.3.0 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from zeep==3.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 48)) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml>=0.4.1 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from zeep==3.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 48)) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from zeep==3.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 48)) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.2.0 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from zeep==3.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 48)) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt>=0.7.1 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from zeep==3.4.0->-r requirements.txt (line 48)) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32->-r requirements.txt (line 32)) (303)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12.2->gevent==20.9.0->-r requirements.txt (line 9)) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in d:\odoo\odoo 15\env\env\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->ofxparse==0.19->-r requirements.txt (line 22)) (2.3.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: psutil
  Building wheel for psutil (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\Odoo\Odoo 15\env\env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Kaiser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s2w1_qhs\\psutil_e01188cc77cd49048b68c594b6f04be2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Kaiser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s2w1_qhs\\psutil_e01188cc77cd49048b68c594b6f04be2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bas0zd91'
       cwd: C:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s2w1_qhs\psutil_e01188cc77cd49048b68c594b6f04be2\
  Complete output (46 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_psaix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_memory_leaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  copying psutil\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
  running build_ext
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil\arch
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil\arch\windows
  "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSUTIL_VERSION=566 -DPSUTIL_WINDOWS=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x01000 -D_AVAIL_WINVER_=0x01000 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 "-ID:\Odoo\Odoo 15\env\env\include" -IC:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpsutil/_psutil_common.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil/_psutil_common.obj
  _psutil_common.c
  "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSUTIL_VERSION=566 -DPSUTIL_WINDOWS=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x01000 -D_AVAIL_WINVER_=0x01000 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 "-ID:\Odoo\Odoo 15\env\env\include" -IC:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\Kaiser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-ID:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpsutil/_psutil_windows.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil/_psutil_windows.obj
  _psutil_windows.c
  psutil/_psutil_windows.c(272): error C2094: label 'error' was undefined
  error: command 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
```

It seems that there is something wrong with 'psutil'. I spent hours looking for a solution but nothing helpful.
These are what I have tried so far:

- Uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio
- Install older version of Visual Studio
- Install C++ Build Tools
- Reinstall Python
- `pip install psutil` works fine but I really don't know what happen with the 'building wheel'

I have Windows 10, python 3.9,
[Build Tools C++ checklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBGXp.png). Really appreciate your help as I am really stressful with this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `psutil` version 5.6.7.

[Source](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/62919)

Comment: It really helped. Thank you so much

Comment: @JohanPham If this answers your question, please consider accepting it.